# Disqus SSO not working - Disqus Docs seems to be deprecated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-sign-on, disqus

I want to integrate SSO with Disqus on my website.

I've got my remote_auth_s3 and my public_api_key set. I can see them in threadDetails.json query Headers (X-Disqus-Publisher-API-Key and X-Disqus-Remote-Auth).

My domains are configured (localhost AND another public domain name).

And for some reason it still doesn't log me in.

In the documentation they talk about the SSO debug tool at this address http://disqus.com/api/sso/. But it doesn't exist anymore.

I can't find a way to debug this... 
Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. **I needed Disqus to enable SSO for my application**. 
Now that SSO is enable I've got a new tab SSO in my application admin where I can debug my SSO payload.

Comment: How can i enable SSO for my application.!?i mean should i tell disqus admin to enable sso in my site!? if yes then can you tell me how to do that!?

Comment: @SuriyaKumar sorry, this thread is old and I havent used Discuss since then.